# Laser Laws (Washington State/U.S.)

Tags: commerce, washington

I'm interested in purchasing a laser source for some product development as a side project, however I understand lasers are a touchy subject.

So, what are some proper avenues to pursue when attempting to purchase a laser either domestically or from a foreign supplier?

Alternatively, can any directly provide information on what regulations and procedures are in place when trying to purchase a laser source in the U.S.?

I live in Washington state and I'm potentially looking at about a 10W laser (20W max!) for the project.

Comment: Synrad in Mukilteo could give you credible advice w.r.t. regulatory details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for product recommendations are not related to law; Tue question of which laws apply is extremely broad and depends on information not present.

Comment: @Nij I'm not looking for recommendations other than how to properly abide by the law. feetwet was able to appropriately answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All laser products entering commerce in the U.S. are regulated by the FDA.  Current regulations are given in [21 CFR 1040](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/cfrsearch.cfm?FR=1040.10).

To save you some time: With power over 5mW you're generally talking about Class IV lasers.  It appears that regulations require such lasers to have a number of safety features, including:

- Master key
- Safety interlocks
- Remote shutoff
- Emission indicator
- Aperture shutter

(There are some "shady" operations that sell electronic *kits* that can be readily assembled to emit as much as 3W, and which do not comply with FDA regulations.  However I have never seen a more powerful laser product for sale that was not compliant.  And the FDA is not known for its sense of humor; enforcement is strict, so I wouldn't be very concerned about a seller lying about compliance of its products.)